# Include JS File in another JS file

Tags: javascript

I need some help.
So, i have a js file which contains themes for maps.
I want to include it to my another js file,and call all themes to make a option for selecting map theme.

Here is my code for map themes:

```
     green_theme: [{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "color": "#aee2e0"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#abce83"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#769E72"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#7B8758"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#EBF4A4"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi.park",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }, {
                "color": "#8dab68"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#5B5B3F"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#ABCE83"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#A4C67D"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#9BBF72"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#EBF4A4"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "color": "#87ae79"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#7f2200"
            }, {
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }, {
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "weight": 4.1
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#495421"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }],

        black_theme: [{
            "stylers": [{
                "hue": "#ff1a00"
            }, {
                "invert_lightness": true
            }, {
                "saturation": -100
            }, {
                "lightness": 33
            }, {
                "gamma": 0.5
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#2D333C"
            }]
        }],

        blue_theme: [{
            "featureType": "landscape.natural",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "color": "#e0efef"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "hue": "#1900ff"
            }, {
                "color": "#c0e8e8"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "lightness": 100
            }, {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit.line",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }, {
                "lightness": 700
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#7dcdcd"
            }]
        }],

        retro_theme: [{
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "elementType": "labels",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#84afa3"
            }, {
                "lightness": 52
            }]
        }, {
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -17
            }, {
                "gamma": 0.36
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit.line",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#3f518c"
            }]
        }]
```

And here is my code for another js file:

```
var options = {
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID ,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                streetViewControl: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.435947810360242, 121.01270109415054),
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
            }
        };

        //refresh map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include JS files, you can include them into HTML files in an order you want like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/first_js.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/second_js.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

also you can use jQuery's get script functionality:

```
$.getScript("second_js.js", function(){

   alert("Script loaded.");

});
```

or you can include any JS to HTML programmatically like this:

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include two different files in HTML and use first file code in second file code:

```
<head>
    <script src="green_theme.js"></script>
    <script src="main_script.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

Or you can use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

```
$.getScript("green_theme.js", function () {
    var options = {/* ... */};
});
```

Comment: how can i include or call the themes?like making a html view listing all map themes on that js file

Comment: @JohnMichaelRivera Array of themes in single variable or multiple variables for each theme

Comment: Array of themes